# Firebase Query all users with nested childs , with conditions (Nodejs)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I make query to create reports to all users with this structure. I read the documentations, but it seems I can't really make those kinds of queries, for eg: I want to query all users that have insurances of animals that are active.

```
users
  uuid
   ...
   insurances -> Animals
                 1 -> state:active 
                           date:...
                 2 -> state:requested
                           date:...

  ...
```

[image]

Comment: I recommend using firestore instead of the realtime database for queries.

Comment: @Swoox yeah i know but the project was build in firebase , cant migrate it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries operate on a flat list of child nodes under the location you query. They can only order/filter on values that are at a known path under each direct child.

Since your values are under `insurances/Animals/???`, it can't query those values.

You'll typically need to solve this by one of these:

1. Creating a flat list of all animals for the query. Each animal in this list must have at least the value you want to filter on, but can be a complete duplicate of the animal information under each user.
2. Giving each user a property that indicates whether they have any insured animal, or the number of insured animals they have, and update that when you update the insurances. That way you can query with `firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("insuredAnimalCount").startAt(1)`.

Also see my answer here:
[Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)